# Как поместить PSB файл в поле скрипта из инспектора?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно из кода работать со слоями в PSB-файле, для этого его нужно через инспектор прокинуть в SerializeField скрипта, вопрос: как? Какой класс представляет PSB в юнити?

Comment: Какой класс? Никакой! Безумие, этот формат не для видеоигр. Если нужны слои, сохрани раздельно, а лучше атлас.

Comment: Я объясню подробнее. В файле не просто набор спрайтов, если бы было так, я бы конечно сразу использовал спрайт атлас и не задавал глупых вопросов :)
К этим спрайтам также привязаны кости и у каждого есть меш. На основании этого ассета построена скелетная анимация персонажа, мне нужно извлекать эти спрайты и заменять ими спрайты в другом, настроенном, GameObject'e.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще чем казалось. Для обращения к спрайтам в PSB достаточно представить его как простой GameObject, а далее через GetComponentsInChildren получить все необходимые элементы.